# SharePoint Timer job not working after deploying wsp successfully

Tags: sharepoint, deployment, wsp

Hi I deployed SharePoint Timer Job wsp successfully using **stsadm** command tool and Central administration and it was deployed globally.

I can see it **deployed** in Central Administration -> System Settings -> Manage Farm solutions.

But I still can't see my timer job in Central Administration -> Monitoring -> Check Job Status.

So I can't set the schedule for my timer job and it is not working.

Do I need other steps to run my timer job?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I can think of two possibilities

1. Do you have provisioning code for your feature which actually loads the job into a SharePoint context?
2. If you have created the provision code have you activated the feature (this isn't always automatic)

**1. Provision Code**

The provisioning code is added to the features event receiver (right click the feature in Visual Studio). You should end up with something similar to the code at the following location [SharePoint 2010 Custom Timer Job](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/office/SharePoint-2010-Custom-416cd3a1)

**2. Activated Feature**

I believe timer jobs can be activated at two scopes in SharePoint (maybe more with services). If your timer job feature was scoped to the "Farm" level, then check that it is active within central administration at 
    `http://<Central Admin URL>/_admin/ManageFarmFeatures.aspx`

If the timer job feature was scoped to the "Web Application" level, then check that it is active within central administration at `http://<Central Admin URL>/_admin/WebApplicationList.aspx`, then select the target web application and click on "Manage Features" on the ribbon.

Comment: > Thanks for the answer.
But unfortunately, I don't fully understand what you have written due to my ignorance in SharePoint.
What is Provision code ?
My timer job is deployed globally so i guess it's in the Farm level.
Am I right?

Thanks again.

Comment: Creating a timer job for SharePoint is great but you have to write code to actually tell SharePoint about the job and when to run it.

You could think of it a bit like creating a custom Class in a .net console application. Creating the class is great, but unless you create an object from the class such as calling the constructor in the "main" method, then none of the code will run.

SharePoint is no different, the example link in step 1 above shows an example of the timer job loading code from the line "public override void FeatureActivated(SPFeatureReceiverProperties properties)"